# Как вывести просто символ одинарной кавыки ' на экран в СИ?

Tags: c++, c

Хочу вывести на экран одинарную кавычку. Как это сделать?

Comment: `cout << '\'';`

Comment: `putchar('\'');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("Символ одинарной кавычки: \' \n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для того чтобы вывести символ одинарной кавычки в Си, необходимо использовать экранирование этого символа с помощью обратной косой черты \.

Comment: В строковом литерале экранирование не нужно

Comment: это один из вариантов))

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще зная кодировку символа: \код символа. Если ASCII:  " \x27 "